# Make this slider auto play

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

How do I make this slider auto play? I've tried just about everything, and I'm not that great at javascript. If anyone has any ideas on I can make this thing auto play and be able to set the speed that would be amazing!

Here is my current markup.

```js
var item_length = $('.swiper-slide > div').length - 1;
var slider = $('.swiper-slide').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 1000,
    fade: true,
    slide: 'div',
    cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
 
 .swiper-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Fix of Webkit flickering */
  z-index: 1;
}
.swiper-container-no-flexbox .swiper-slide {
  float: left;
}
.swiper-container-vertical > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.swiper-container-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}
.swiper-container-multirow > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.swiper-container-free-mode > .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper-slide {
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/* Auto Height */
.swiper-container-autoheight,
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}
.swiper-container-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, height;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
  transition-property: transform, height;
}

/* Pagination Styles */
.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  -moz-transition: 300ms;
  -o-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10;
}
.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
/* Common Styles */
.swiper-pagination-fraction,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Bullets */
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: #fff;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ed1b2e;
}
.swiper-pagination-white .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #fff;
}
.swiper-pagination-black .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: #000;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

/* Preloader */
.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  -moz-animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s steps(12, end) infinite;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%236c6c6c'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
  background-position: 50%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.swiper-lazy-preloader-white:after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20120%20120'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cline%20id%3D'l'%20x1%3D'60'%20x2%3D'60'%20y1%3D'7'%20y2%3D'27'%20stroke%3D'%23fff'%20stroke-width%3D'11'%20stroke-linecap%3D'round'%2F%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(30%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(60%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(90%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(120%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.27'%20transform%3D'rotate(150%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.37'%20transform%3D'rotate(180%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.46'%20transform%3D'rotate(210%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.56'%20transform%3D'rotate(240%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.66'%20transform%3D'rotate(270%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.75'%20transform%3D'rotate(300%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3Cuse%20xlink%3Ahref%3D'%23l'%20opacity%3D'.85'%20transform%3D'rotate(330%2060%2C60)'%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
@-webkit-keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HERO SLIDER -->
<div class="swiper-container" style="margin-top:-40px;">
<div class="swiper-wrapper"><!-- SLIDE 1 -->
<div class="swiper-slide"><a href="/search.html?q="><img alt="" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/content/deichmann/obs/Media/Mobile%2DApp%2DMedia/20161206%2DBOGO50.gif" width="100%" /></a></div>
<!-- END --><!-- SLIDE 2 -->

<div class="swiper-slide"><a href="/search.html?q=%3Arelevance%3Abrand%3ANike"><img alt="" src="http://deichmann.scene7.com/is/image/deichmann/20161206-NIKESALEWEEK?wid=580&amp;fmt=gif" width="100%" /></a></div>
<!-- END --></div>

<div class="swiper-pagination">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!-- END HERO SLIDER -->
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You must include jquery *before* the plugin.
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>`